# Como adicionar texto em um QPlainTextEdit(PYQT5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt-5

A principio gostaria apenas de saber como adicionar valores em um TextEdit, porem meu objetivo é pegar os valores dos dois comboBoxs e usa-los para gerar a senha.

Segue o codigo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'GestorDeSenhas.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QToolTip,QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter

class Ui_frameGerador(object):
    def setupUi(self, frameGerador):
        frameGerador.setObjectName("frameGerador")
        frameGerador.setEnabled(True)
        frameGerador.resize(489, 310)
        frameGerador.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(489, 0))
        frameGerador.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(927, 310))
        frameGerador.setStyleSheet("QWidget#frameGerador{\n"
"background-color: white;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"color: black;\n"
"height: 25px;\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border: 2px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(frameGerador)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(20, -1, 20, -1)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(frameGerador)
        self.label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(frameGerador)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.cboxQntsSenhas = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(frameGerador)
        self.cboxQntsSenhas.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.WheelFocus)
        self.cboxQntsSenhas.setStyleSheet("")
        self.cboxQntsSenhas.setMinimum(1)
        self.cboxQntsSenhas.setProperty("value", 1)
        self.cboxQntsSenhas.setObjectName("cboxQntsSenhas")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.cboxQntsSenhas)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(frameGerador)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.cboxDigitos = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(frameGerador)
        self.cboxDigitos.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.WheelFocus)
        self.cboxDigitos.setStyleSheet("broder-radius:20pt;")
        self.cboxDigitos.setMinimum(1)
        self.cboxDigitos.setObjectName("cboxDigitos")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.cboxDigitos)
        self.radioMaiusculasMinusculas = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(frameGerador)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        self.radioMaiusculasMinusculas.setFont(font)
        self.radioMaiusculasMinusculas.setChecked(False)
        self.radioMaiusculasMinusculas.setAutoRepeat(False)
        self.radioMaiusculasMinusculas.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.radioMaiusculasMinusculas.setObjectName("radioMaiusculasMinusculas")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(9, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.radioMaiusculasMinusculas)
        self.radioCaracEspeciais = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(frameGerador)
        self.radioCaracEspeciais.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
        self.radioCaracEspeciais.setChecked(False)
        self.radioCaracEspeciais.setAutoRepeat(False)
        self.radioCaracEspeciais.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.radioCaracEspeciais.setObjectName("radioCaracEspeciais")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(10, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.radioCaracEspeciais)
        self.txtBoxResultado = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(frameGerador)
        self.txtBoxResultado.setEnabled(True)
        self.txtBoxResultado.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.txtBoxResultado.setObjectName("txtBoxResultado")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(11, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.txtBoxResultado)
        self.frameButtons = QtWidgets.QFrame(frameGerador)
        self.frameButtons.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.frameButtons.setStyleSheet("QFrame#frameButtons{\n"
"border: 1px;\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.frameButtons.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frameButtons.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frameButtons.setObjectName("frameButtons")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frameButtons)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, -1, 0, -1)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.btnGerar = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frameButtons)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btnGerar.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btnGerar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btnGerar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.btnGerar.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(1, 0))
        self.btnGerar.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btnGerar.setDefault(True)
        self.btnGerar.setObjectName("btnGerar")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btnGerar)
        self.btnSair = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frameButtons)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btnSair.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btnSair.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btnSair.setObjectName("btnSair")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btnSair)
        self.formLayout.setWidget(14, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.frameButtons)

        self.retranslateUi(frameGerador)
        self.btnSair.clicked.connect(frameGerador.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(frameGerador)
        frameGerador.setTabOrder(self.cboxQntsSenhas, self.cboxDigitos)
        frameGerador.setTabOrder(self.cboxDigitos, self.radioMaiusculasMinusculas)
        frameGerador.setTabOrder(self.radioMaiusculasMinusculas, self.radioCaracEspeciais)
        frameGerador.setTabOrder(self.radioCaracEspeciais, self.btnGerar)
        frameGerador.setTabOrder(self.btnGerar, self.btnSair)
        frameGerador.setTabOrder(self.btnSair, self.txtBoxResultado)


        self.btnGerar.clicked.connect(self.addValorGerado)


    def addValorGerado(self):
        self.txtBoxResultado.clear()







    def retranslateUi(self, frameGerador):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        frameGerador.setWindowTitle(_translate("frameGerador", "Form"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("frameGerador", "Gerador de senhas"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("frameGerador", "Quantas senhas:"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("frameGerador", "Digitos: "))
        self.radioMaiusculasMinusculas.setText(_translate("frameGerador", "Incluir Maiusculas e minusculas"))
        self.radioCaracEspeciais.setText(_translate("frameGerador", "Incluiir caracteres especiais"))
        self.btnGerar.setText(_translate("frameGerador", "Gerar"))
        self.btnSair.setText(_translate("frameGerador", "Sair"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    frameGerador = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_frameGerador()
    ui.setupUi(frameGerador)
    frameGerador.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Os Widget `PlainTextEdit` tem associado a ele um objeto do tipo `QTextDocument` - é esse objeto que tem os métodos e atributos tanto para ler o conteúdo digitado pelo usuário, como para mudar o conteúdo, ou configurar a apresentação. (Já aspectos como localização do cursor, largura do mesmo, são configurados diretamente no objeto `QPlainTextEdit`)

O método `.document()` retorna esse objeto associado ao editor, que por sua vez tem o método `.setHtml()` que permite inserir o conteúdo desejado no editor. 
Você pode enviar uma string com qualquer HTML válido, inclusive com estilo inline - automaticamente o Qt vai traduzir o seu HTML para o estilo que ele usa internamente (extensões formatadas de texto usam a tag `<span ...>`, mesmo que sejam enviadas com a tag `<h1>`, por exemplo).

Então, no seu caso, poderia simplesmente fazer, no ponto desejado:

```
doc = self.txtBoxresultado.document()
doc.setHtml("""<h1>Senhas Geradas:</h1>abc123<br/>qazwsx<br/>123456<br/>""")
```

E fica a dica para a próxima vez que fizer uma pergunta: 
Reduza o seu código para conter apenas o que você precisa resolver - um exemplo mínimo, autocontido e verificável - isso é, que qualquer um com Pyqt5 instalado possa copiar e rodar, e que tenha só a janela e o TextEditor . Enviando a pergunta desse jeito você obriga as pessoas a estudarem o seu programa todo, para tirar uma dúvida apenas pontual.

Comment: o QPlainTextEdit tem slots para não precisar do document diretamente `insertPlainText(const QString & text)` `appendPlainText(const QString & text)` `setPlainText(const QString & text)` - curiosamente tem até o `appendHtml(const QString & html)`, que apesar de não aceitar tabelas e floats, serve para formatação de parágrafos via HTML. [docs (en)](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html#appendHtml)

Comment: hmm -- verdade - estou mais acostumado com tkinter, que exige sempre objetos intermediários para lidar com o texto dos widgets. Os bindings de Python inclusive não precisam desse casting - strings normais de Python podem ser usadas em todos esses métodos.

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Sou iniciante, e ja havia tentado de todas as formas que eu pude imaginar de fazer isso.

Comment: Realmente muito obrigado! Me ajudou muito!

Comment: @jsbueno ah, é que eu copiei direto do manual original (C++), é só descrição do tipo mesmo. Eu geralmente pego direto da documentação da Qt, apesar de na prática eu geralmente usar bindings em Harbour e até os de Py mais raramente. O wrapper para Harbour que eu uso também aceita, sempre que possível, os tipos nativos